# Print a struct with a known size

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some structs that may contain some certain number of unsigned integer (They are either uint32_t or uint64_t). I want to print out the value of these struct in an understandable way. 
For example I may have a struct like below.

```
struct test {
    uint32_t ab = 0;
    uint64_t cd = 1;
    uint32_t ef = 2;
};
```

I think I could have a method pass the address of this struct and print it out by using the size of this struct. But not sure how to write the code.

Comment: Even if you have the size of the struct... you still don't have the exact type of each member. To do what you want, you'll need (static) reflection. C++ doesn't have it yet, despite work being done towards it in future standard revisions.

Comment: I know that each member is either uint32_t or uint64_t. Would that be helpful? Some basic understanding about the information that struct contains would be ok for me.

Comment: Not enough I'm afraid. If they can appear in any order and in any number, you can't tell anything from a structure address and size alone.

Comment: With C++14, you could use [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, C++11 has no reflection mechanism. The only way to obtain a list of members is to role out your own mechanism. Since you mentioned each member always has one of two types, it should be fairly straight forward. For instance, by creating a trait class.

```
template<class T>
struct mem_ptr {
    // Tagged union type to generically refer to a member of a struct T
    enum {u32, u64} alive;
    union {
        uint32_t T::* u32_ptr;
        uint64_t T::* u64_ptr;
    };
    mem_ptr(uint32_t T::* u32_ptr) : alive(u32), u32_ptr(u32_ptr) {}
    mem_ptr(uint64_t T::* u64_ptr) : alive(u64), u64_ptr(u64_ptr) {}
};

template<class> struct struct_members;

template<>
struct struct_members<test> {
    mem_ptr<test> members[3] = {
      &test::ab, &test::cd, &test::ef
    };
};

template<class T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& str) -> decltype(struct_members<T>::members, os) {
    struct_members<T> const mem;
    char const *delim = "";
    os << "{ ";
    for(auto& m : mem.members) {
        os << delim;
        delim = ", ";
        switch(m.alive) {
            case m.u32: os << (str.*(m.u32_ptr)); break;
            case m.u64: os << (str.*(m.u64_ptr)); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    os << " }";
    return os;
}
```

Putting the above to the test (pun intended) on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gA99qlCbS6BmTBmQ), prints:

```
{ 0, 1, 2 }
```

With that in-place, you can add support for a new structure by just defining the `struct_members` table for it:

```
struct test2 {
    uint32_t ab1 = 5;
    uint64_t cd2 = 3;
    uint32_t ef3 = 8;
};

template<>
struct struct_members<test2> {
    mem_ptr<test2> members[3] = {
      &test2::ab1, &test2::cd2, &test2::ef3
    };
};
```

And the stream operator previously written will work for it too.

Comment: _Technically_ there are ways to figure out the number of members and "tuplify" them by (ab)using brace initialization and structured bindings...

Comment: @MaxLanghof - You mean like Polukhin's magic_get? Wasn't it limited to C++14 and above? The question is tagged C++11.

Comment: Oh right, structured bindings are obviously out if we're in C++11. I need to pay more attention to language tags.

Comment: In what respect it is better than just writing a function saying `std::cout << x.ab << '  ' << x.cd << '  ' x.de;`?

Comment: @aparpara - Several ways. (1) It works with all standard streams types, not just `std::cout`. (2) The logic is centralized, and there is no need to write a function for *every* type that tries to keep to the same format. Less prone to copy paste errors. (3) The same table can be used in a similar `operator >>` to read a type back from a text file. And possibly in other places where this sort of reflective information may be of use.

Comment: @StoryTeller, looks like the reasons are not valid. Because (1) If you want to work with all standard stream types, you can easily make the stream a parameter. (2) You still need to write `struct_members` for *every* type. (3) The question is about printing, but if you want a full-fledged serialization, no need to invent bicycle, there is `boost::serialization` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion

Comment: @aparpara - Yes, the members, not the logic. Similiraly to  how boost::serialization requires its own hooks. Regardless, the OP already commented under their post they want *some info* about the members. This answer is geared to that bit of info. But it's okay if you disapprove, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just a basic understanding about what is inside, you may reinterpret the structure as an array of `uint32_t`-s and print them in hex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct test {
    uint32_t ab = 0;
    uint64_t cd = 1;
    uint32_t ef = 2;
};

// For those who don't respect strict aliasing rules mentioned in comments
/*
template<class T>
void printStruct(const T& s)
{
    auto* b = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(&s);
    auto* e = b + sizeof(T)/sizeof(uint32_t);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    for (auto* i = b; i != e; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(sizeof(uint32_t)*2) << std::setfill('0') << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::dec;
}
*/

// For those who do respect strict aliasing rules mentioned in comments
template<class T>
void printStruct(const T& s)
{
    const auto sc = sizeof(char);
    const auto n = sizeof(uint32_t)/sc;
    auto* b = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&s);
    auto* e = b + sizeof(T)/(sc*n);

    std::cout << std::hex;
    for (auto* i = b; i != e; i += n)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            // For a big-endian machine n - 1 - j must be replaced by j
            std::cout << std::setw(sc*2) << std::setfill('0') << *(i + n - 1 - j);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::dec;
}

int main()
{
    printStruct(test());
    return 0;
}
```

But the routine will print also alignment bytes and on a little-endian machine the two parts of an `uint64_t` will be reversed.

E.g. on my machine it prints

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000002 00007ffe
```

Where the first `00000000` is `ab`, the second `00000000` is alignment, `00000001 00000000` is `cd`, `00000002` is `de` and `00007ffe` is alignment again.

Comment: That is undefined behavior (by violating strict aliasing). You are allowed to inspect objects via a (possibly `unsigned`) `char*`, but not through `uint32_t*`. Although you can easily get the same result by doing it that way.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, strictly speaking, you are right. But in this particular case I can't see what may be the source of the undefined behavior. And yes, one can print the same as `sizeof(uint32_t)/sizeof(char)` unsigned chars.

Comment: The source of undefined behavior is not fallowing a "shall" requirement by the C++ standard. Code having UB or not in this case in not negotiable I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, let's pay tribute to the C++ standard "shall" :)

Comment: I prefer to pay tribute to portable programs that don't break when various sanitizers are ran on them, or compilers given free reign to optimize. But sure, let's be sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `std::tuple` for your structures. e.g. your struct could be defined as:

```
typedef std::tuple< uint32_t, uint64_t, uint32_t > test;
```

You can then print any tuple using:

```
template<class Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct TuplePrinter {
    static void print(const Tuple& t)
    {
        TuplePrinter<Tuple, N - 1>::print(t);
        std::cout << ", " << std::get<N - 1>(t);
    }
};

template<class Tuple>
struct TuplePrinter<Tuple, 1> {
    static void print(const Tuple& t)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(t);
    }
};

template<class... Args>
void print(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    std::cout << "(";
    TuplePrinter<decltype(t), sizeof...(Args)>::print(t);
    std::cout << ")\n";
}
```

If you want to get back your named members you could derive a struct from your tuple, something like this:

```
struct test : public std::tuple< uint32_t, uint64_t, uint32_t >
{
    typedef std::tuple< uint32_t, uint64_t, uint32_t > base;
    test()
    : base( 0, 1, 2 ),
      ab( std::get< 0 >( *this ) ),
      cd( std::get< 1 >( *this ) ),
      ef( std::get< 2 >( *this ) )
    {
    }
    uint32_t& ab;
    uint64_t& cd;
    uint32_t& ef;
};
```

or alternatively:

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T& t)
{
    print(t.tuple);
}

struct test
{
    uint32_t ab = 0;
    uint64_t cd = 1;
    uint32_t ef = 2;
    typedef std::tuple< uint32_t&, uint64_t&, uint32_t& > tuple_t;
    const tuple_t tuple = { ab, cd, ef };
};
```

or (as suggested by @Jarod42):

```
void print(const test& t)
{
    print(std::tie(t.ab, t.cd, t.ef));
}
```

Comment: I would do a little different, provide a method similar to `auto as_tuple(test t) { return std::tie(t.ab, t.cd, t.ef); }`. So you keep name member, and you don't have bigger structure.